# Testing if a row exists in a table for a report

Tags: ms-access, join, report

I'm trying to write a report that lists all the rows from a master table and inserts a field ("Y"/"N") if the key exists in a current-use table.  For example, the COLOR_MASTER table has 256 colors by COLOR_NAME (field/key).  The CURRENT_PROJECTS has a row for each project and the COLOR_NAME (field).  I want to list all the COLOR_MASTER rows and then on the same print line a "Y" or "N" if that COLOR_NAME is used in the CURRENT_PROJECTS table.

I've tried to mess around with it in the Design View and have had no luck.  The JOIN that was created looks basically like this and how I want the report is following the dashes:

```
RIGHT JOIN COLOR_MASTER ON CURRENT_PROJECTS.COLOR_NAME = 
   COLOR_MASTER.COLOR_NAME ON CURRENT_PROJECTS.COLOR_NAME = 
   COLOR_MASTER.COLOR_NAME;
--------
       Color                                 Used
   BLUE                                     
   RED                                        Y
   YELLOW
```

I have no expertise in JOINs and I don't understand why this JOIN was created or what I need to do to fix it. Based on my reading, I guess it's trying to do an outer join.

Currently, I'm just trying to show the COLOR_NAME if used as I don't know how to test that it is used and convert it to "Y".  I don't care if the color is used once or twenty times and I don't really want any data from the CURRENT_PROJECTS table.

Under the "Used" column I now have "#Error" on all lines. So, I'm figuring that the RIGHT JOIN has an error.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps build an aggregate query that counts the colors in Current_Projects. Join that query to Color_Master.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll need to do some research on "aggregate query" has I have no idea what you mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the RIGHT JOIN is defined in the table Relationships builder and a query using the tables adopts the established link. If you want to change the join type in a query then with query in design view, double click on the line linking tables to open the Join Properties dialog.

If there is only one record per project in Current_Projects and a color can be used only once, simply:

```
SELECT Color_Master.Color_Name, IIf([Current_Projects].[Color_Name] Is Null,"N","Y") AS Used
FROM Color_Master LEFT JOIN Current_Projects ON Color_Master.Color_Name = Current_Projects.Color_Name;
```

However, it sounds like each color can be used for multiple projects. So will need to use GROUP BY or DISTINCT query joined to the Master_Colors table:

`SELECT DISTINCT Current_Projects.Color_Name FROM Current_Projects;`

```
SELECT Color_Master.Color_Name, IIf([Query1].[Color_Name] Is Null,"N","Y") AS Used
FROM Query1 RIGHT JOIN Color_Master ON Query1.Color_Name = Color_Master.Color_Name;
```

Here is all-in-one SQL:

```
SELECT Color_Master.Color_Name, IIf([Query1].[Color_Name] Is Null,"N","Y") AS Used
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Current_Projects.Color_Name FROM Current_Projects) AS Query1 
RIGHT JOIN Color_Master ON Query1.Color_Name = Color_Master.Color_Name;
```

If you don't want anything displayed for the N result then use Null without quote marks in the expression.

An alternative is DLookup() but domain aggregate functions can perform slowly in query or textbox expression.

Advise not to save the calculated value to table, just calculate when needed.

Comment: Thank you, June.  I updated the SELECT as your all-in-one. I then tried to add a field from the Current_Projects (e.g. Project_Name).  I added a comma after Used and then Current_Projects.Project_Name.  It is prompting me for input (like a selection test) for Current_Projects.Project_Name.  I'm sure I have something wrong.

Comment: Current_Projects table is not in the all-in-one query. Color_Master and Query1 are in the query. The desired output described in your question does not allow for Project_Name and it really makes no sense to include.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it all in one query. Start by building a query that as the IDs of all the colors currently in use. Name it something like `ColorsInUse` and save it.

It could be something as simple as:

```
SELECT [COLOR_NAME] FROM [CURRENT_PROJECTS] GROUP BY [COLOR_NAME]
```

Then all you have to do is run the following queries:

```
UPDATE [COLOR_MASTER] SET [MyField]="N"
UPDATE [COLOR_MASTER] SET [MyField]="Y" WHERE [COLOR_NAME] IN [ColorsInUse]
```

Another way of doing it is by using `DLookup`. Something like this:

```
UPDATE [COLOR_MASTER] SET [MyField]=IIF(NZ(DLookup("[COLOR_NAME]","[CURRENT_PROJECTS]","[COLOR_NAME]='" & [COLOR_NAME] & "'"),"")="","N","Y")
```

Some notes: You should not use a text field (like a name) as your key. You should always use numerical IDs. You should also never use a text Y/N. Use an actual Yes/No field instead.

Comment: Thx, SunKnight.  I guess a separate query updating a table is the best way to go and not that difficult to implement.